# Masking a raster file using another file with different resolution and

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gdal, rasterio

I have two raster files (ras1 and ras2) with differently extent and resolution. I need to overlap them to mask values of ras1 with ras2. I am using python and packages (e.g., geopandas, shapely, rasterio) to preform the analysis. I was wondering what is the best way to overlap layers (and pixels one by one  with same size and same position) to mask them? For example, should I clip ras1 (larger extent) using the boundary of ras2 (smaller extent) and than resample pixels of ras1 to overlap pixels of two layers exactly? I mean how I can overlap relevant pixels of two layers exactly?
Here is how layers are overlapped.

[image]

Comment: You should try to give a workable example with inputs and desired output.